# messagebox popping up twice (regex)

Tags: regex, vb.net

so here is my problem, so when I type in a digit into the `txtFullNameAdminAddPatientTextbox` , it pops up a `messagebox` showing "please only enter digit. But the problem is, why does it pop up the `messagebox` TWICE? thanks in advance

```
 If (Not (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtFullNameAdminAddPatientPage.Text, "^[a-zA-Z\s]+$"))) Then
            txtFullNameAdminAddPatientPage.Text = ""
            MessageBox.Show("Please only enter digit.")
        End If
```

Comment: Is it tied to an event?

Comment: Presumably it is because you are setting the `Text` of that `TextBox` back to an empty `String` and that doesn't satisfy the regex either. Of course, you could always debug your code and find out for yourself.

Comment: Also, cut out the disgraceful tag spamming. Abusing tags to get more people to look at your needless question is not the way to make friends around here. That you have no badges shows that you ignored the prompt to view the site tour when you registered, so you're not trying very hard at all. You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to use this site properly or you'll likely find your questions getting closed quite quickly.

Comment: I bet it is in `TextChaned` event. That would explain the message box showing twice.

Comment: Are you required to use RegEx? It would look a lot simpler with .TryParse.

Comment: @Mary yes it is a textchanged event, so how to prevent the messagebox, form popping out twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Validating event and the ErrorProvider class.

```
Private err As New ErrorProvider()

Private Sub txtFullNameAdminAddPatientPage_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles txtFullNameAdminAddPatientPage.Validating
    If Not Integer.TryParse(txtFullNameAdminAddPatientPage.Text, Nothing) Then
        e.Cancel = True
        err.SetError(TextBox1, "This text box must be a number.")
    Else
        err.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this code for validation . Add this code in LostFocus event of textbox.